# Spring boot unable to run schema.sql

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am on spring boot 2.3, and have following in my schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE customer (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255));
```

Pom file has h2 dependency.

When I run application, I get error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name) VALUES ($1, $2) [42102-200]
```

Is some change needed in application.properties to make spring boot execute schema.sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop table if exist before creation :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;

CREATE TABLE customer (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255));
```